# Anime involving rebirth and a WW2 battleship outfitted for space

Tags: story-identification, anime

I saw this as a feature length VHS hired from the local video store in the mid-to-late 1980s, in English.

I'm not sure of the plot, but it was animated.

The general points I remember are quite vivid:

- a WW2 battleship outfitted for space
- a scene right at the end where two characters are laying down on a shoreline with waves lapping at their feet - one of them dies, and the focus is briefly solely on the other character, but immediately reveals that in place of the first character there is now a baby
- a scene where a character is trying to be convinced to go on a mission, and is introduced to some weapons training which consists of a shooting range, but the targets are living humanoid creatures, including children, which are pushed into the shooting range

Comment: The first point means it should be one of the *Space Battleship Yamato*. I have however not seen all of them and so cannot confirm if the two scenes you mention are in one of them

Comment: Yes, an anime seen in the 1980s with a battleship reused as a spaceship screams Space Battleship Yamato.  The series was 1974-75. A condensed movie version of the series was released in 1977.  There were a number of sequel series and three sequel movies in 1978, 1979, and 1980.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Battleship_Yamato#Movie_edition  And some of the movies could have been available in English in the 1980s.

Comment: If that anime was Space Battleship Yamato, you may have known it with its first western name, which was "Starblazers".

Comment: So Moo, any input on _Starblazers/Space Battleship Yamato_ suggested above? Is that possibly one of these or should answerers drop that lead?

Comment: @Jenayah the comments above are useful but vague and cover three movies without more than a "that sounds like...", which I'm not really interested in chasing down.  If someone can definitively say "yup, this movie contains those scenes", that's what I'm after.

Comment: @Moo Does this ship look like the one in the anime, if you remember? Space conversion: http://www.shipschematics.net/yamato/images/edf/battleship_yamato.jpg
Seagoing warship: http://www.shipschematics.net/yamato/images/edf/battleship_yamato_1945.jpg

Comment: @SpaceWolf1701 from my vague recollection, yes that may have been the ship from the anime I saw, but the aforementioned specific scenes are what sticks in my mind.

Comment: @Moo Well, the Yamato is the only example of a WWII-naval-vessel-converted-to-spacecraft in an anime, or any fiction, that I know of, so therefore you're talking about one of the movies or the TV shows. So we've at least narrowed it down to that.

Comment: @Moo, is there a chance the VHS contained episodes from different series, or that you are conflating memories of different pieces of animation? Because the _"two characters on a shoreline, one becomes a baby"_ scene is _exactly_ like the one described in https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/200231/40711, but that movie does not seem to match the other points.

Comment: @lfurini oooh, you might have hit on something there - that movie also contains one of my other points, specifically the shooting range with living humanoid targets.  The ending seems to match as well - so I probably have conflated two movies here.  Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [80s-90s anime (movie or series) in which an armored girl exchanges age with a dying man on a beach](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/200141/80s-90s-anime-movie-or-series-in-which-an-armored-girl-exchanges-age-with-a-dy)

Comment: @lfurini - would you mind making that a formal answer before closing as a dupe?

Comment: @fez dutifully done.

Answer (score 3):

Is there a chance the VHS contained episodes from different series, or that you are conflating memories of different pieces of animation?

While *"WW2 battleship outfitted for space"* could be the official 5-word definition for *Space Battleship Yamato* (as pointed out by Ash's answer and other peoples' comments), there is a scene perfectly matching *"two characters on a shoreline, one becomes a baby"* in the movie [*"Phoenix 2772"*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phoenix_2772), which every now and again turns out being the answer to someone's strange recollections.
If that's the case, we already have [a question with a detailed and accepted answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/200231/40711) this could be marked a duplicate of.
That answer also has a YouTube link with the whole subbed movie: having now watched it, the scene with the shooting training is at 0:14:50; the scene on the shore is indeed the final one and starts at about 1:48:15.

Answer (score 1):

I would expect this to be [Space Battleship Yamato](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Battleship_Yamato_(1977_film)) in particular the 1977 film adaptation. The warship definitely fits, and the beach scene rings a bell too. But I would have expected to remember the firing range scene you describe and I can't say that I do.

Comment: Sorry, but this answer doesn't really pin it down enough to warrant an upvote or acceptance.  I'm looking for confirmation of the aforementioned two scenes in a specific film.

Comment: I can't find the exact scene but the people on the beach are likely Mamoru and Starsha on Iscandar, I vaguely remember a similar scene with them towards the end.