# 80's cartoon/anime with an alien that looks like a sunny side up egg

Tags: story-identification, animation

I vaguely remember watching this as a child in the mid nineties. It might be possible that this was not an anime, but something non-Japanese.

I remember there were at least two characters in a space ship stranded in space. A regular looking human guy and a robot or cyborg looking woman. I'm pretty sure the woman had a human looking head with hair but the rest of her body was mechanical. The characters both had pale skin, the robot woman had blonde hair.

At some point the robot woman goes outside to fix the space ship by herself. While she's working a creature that looks like a sunny side up egg attacks her (probably the reason I remember this because I was extremely confused as to why an egg was attacking a robot). The egg crawls inside the robot woman and she faints/stops working.

Thinking about this some more I'm starting to recall a few more details. The alien egg creature doesn't outright attack the robot woman. It's sneaky and attaches itself to her head first without her noticing. Kind of absorbing into her skull after that. I have a feeling this means that there's some sort of possession plot.

The next scene I remember is just the regular looking guy standing over the robot woman looking confused. I guess she made it back inside the space ship before she broke down/fainted. He attempts to revive her by attaching wires to her chest.

I'm not sure if this is useful, but here's some added context. I lived in Russia when I saw this. My father loved anything sci-fi and would watch any movies he could get his hands on. My best guess is that I would have watched this in 1995-96. I'm certain that this wasn't a Russian made cartoon.

The original language or country this cartoon would have been from is hard for me to identify for a few reasons. First, most VHS tapes wouldn't have been originals. It was common for people to sell pirated copies converted into a format that local VHS players could play. Second, these tapes rarely had box art or accurate/correctly translated titles. Unfortunately I don't remember what the title was, and there was no artwork on the VHS tape's box.

Comment: Hey there, this is a great first post but could improve from some of the guidelines offered here: [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: If you saw this in the mid 90s, what made you think it was from the 80s? The art style?

Comment: A lot of movies brought into the country back then were not new. Which is why I assumed this one wasn't either. It's possible that it was made in the early nineties.

Comment: I'm quite sure you are looking for the same cartoon as [this identification question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/200141/40711); the accepted answer has a YouTube link to the whole movie, so you can easily verify. I had a similar recollection of the "egg alien" and was finally able to find its source. I think the scene you remember happens near the end of the movie.

Comment: The "alien egg" scene starts at the [1:21:20 mark](https://youtu.be/V0VkmHwVOkQ?t=4862).

Comment: Yes, I think that must be it!