# Cartoon/anime with astronauts battling a bird creature in space

Tags: story-identification, anime

A very long time ago I saw an anime or cartoon, this was at least 20 years ago, but most likely less then 30.

In the story there were some astronauts battling a bird creature in space. One of the female astronauts got hit by an space-bird-egg, and because she had space-bird-egg-yolk in her hair, she then worked for the bird. Later, the other astronauts confronted her in the lair of the space-bird, and they were confused as to why she switched sides, but as they saw the space-bird-egg-yolk, they were like "of course, the egg caused this!", as if mind-controlling-space-bird-egg-yolk was common knowledge.

I don't remember anything else about it, but I think that the art style was similar to the Daft Punk music videos.

Comment: I guess *Phoenix 2772*. Please take a look at [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/200141/98028) and confirm whether this is the one (the description of the egg scene can be found in [this other post](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/213816/98028)

Comment: I think that is the one, can you post it as answer, then I can accept it.

Comment: Nah, no need to duplicate an existing, better answer. As you confirmed this was the right one, we can now close the question as a duplicate and point toward the "main" question/answer thread, [as is our policy](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7067/98028). This is not a punition of any kind, don't worry :) it's about gathering all the relevant info in a single place.