# Animated movie with a cute little girl, a talking dog, and a talking humanoid robot

Tags: story-identification, movie, robots

Here's everything I remember from this movie:

My family rented a VHS for a single weekend. I watched it three times. I can still picture some images from it, but I don't remember the name or the plot.

They spoke English, and the animation was more Western style.

The three characters I definitely remember are:

- A cute little girl, definitely white, possibly red hair, possibly blond.
- A cocker spaniel (or other dog) that was yellow. Fluffy and has floopy ears, sorta like Lady in the Lady and the Tramp
  but more yellow-brown
- A robot, definitely humanoid like C-3P0, might have been silver or gold or another color.

Both the robot and the dog could talk.

This movie was definitely made before 2006 since that was the year we rented the VHS.

Does this sound familiar to anyone?

The country that I watched this movie in was Canada (specifically the English-speaking province of Ontario).

---

It was not *Robo Story* or *Phoenix 2772*
Nor was it *Wizard of Oz*
Nor was it *Doogal*
Nor was it *Golden Warrior: Gold Lightan*
Nor was it *Inspector Gadget*

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Can you tell us anything about the plot? Where was the story set? Are there any other characters that you can describe, such as any antagonists?

Comment: @HorusKol - Looks like a strong match. You should post it as an answer.

Comment: I was going to suggest *Phoenix 2772* https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/220792/anime-with-a-man-transforming-into-an-orangutan/220795#220795 — but *Robo Story* looks like a better fit.

Comment: Hi @HorusKol, OP here. That was a great guess! It threw me for a loop (almost seemed familiar, like uncanny valley familiar), but then I saw the dog and knew that it wasn't right. The dog from the movie (or TV show?) that I'm remembering had floppier ears and a different animation style.

Comment: @LogicDictates all I can remember is that they spoke English. They *maybe* were trying to save a unicorn but that might be a totally different movie?? There also might have been a castle but that also might have been a different movie.

I'm sorry I don't remember much! Thank you!

Comment: The main characters of Inspector gadget are a girl with blond hair, a yellow-brownish dog and a mostly grey Uncle Gadget, who is not a robot, but is heavily cybernetically enhanced. Animation is in Western style.

Comment: @ErnstdeRidder I love Inspector Gadget but unfortunately this isn't it.

Answer (score 4):

#### Wizard of Oz?

First thing that comes to mind is one of the many animated versions of WoO.

Cute girl with yellow hair, C3P0esque robot, talking dog.

[image: 1982 Animated Version]

Comment: Thank you for your guess, but it wasn't the Wizard of Oz! I can totally see what you're saying though!

Answer (score 3):

Possibly [Golden Warrior: Gold Lightan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_Warrior_Gold_Lightan) (1981-82)

- The robot is gold and talks
- There is a [blonde girl](https://lightan.fandom.com/wiki/Emi_Takakura)
- There is a [yellowish dog](https://lightan.fandom.com/wiki/Chibi)

The dog doesn't talk, as far as I can tell. It's also not a movie, but everything else seems to fit. VHS anime shows were often released as mutli-episode back in the day.

Comment: Thank you for the guess Machavity! Chibi is very cute but unfortunately not the dog I'm looking for (and the humanoid robot was definitely normal-person-sized, not giant)

Answer (score 2):

Could your movie potentially be Doogal (2006)?

Came across this thread while looking for this obscure piece of my childhood memory.

Edit: Seems to be basically a completely different movie outside of the US, called "The Magic Roundabout"

Well, I took a lot of liberties here. With the possibility that OPs memory is as bad as mine, he could be misremembering things. Anyway, there's a little girl that has an English-speaking dog and a hero that sort of looks like a robot (but is actually just some creature on a spring).

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Could you [edit] your answer to explain how _Doogal_ matches the movie described in the question? It'd help other users to tell whether this has a good chance of being the right answer or not.

Comment: Thank you for the guess but definitely not this.