# Need help finding a 1970-1980s (maybe early 90s) dark Space-SciFi Anime

Tags: story-identification, anime

For years I have been trying to find a anime scifi movie that I saw as a child. First and foremost, it is a movie. It is somewhat dark, maybe even towards horror but somewhat also adventurous. The main protagonist is a woman. A specific detail I recall that might help you identify this is that in a particular scene, this woman is isolated in a spaceship and there are odd things there, because first you see her I believe floating but asleep, and a scene later she has this weird headcrab (similar to [Half-Life’s headcrab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headcrab)) on her face, but it looks more like a scrambled egg monster, really weird stuff.

That is all that I can sort of recall. I have seen this in Europe around 1992-1995 ish, but back then in Europe we usually had movies and anime etc that were considerably older (late 70s, 80s), that is why I suggested even late 70s, 80s to early 90s.

It was definitely dark, weird, had odd monsters like this headcrab thing that was suddenly on the girl’s head inside the space ship where she appeard to be completely alone.

Comment: I'm quite sure you are looking for the same cartoon as [this identification question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/200141/40711); the accepted answer has a YouTube link to the whole movie, so you can easily verify. I had a similar recollection of the "egg alien" and was finally able to find its source. The scene starts at the [1:21:20 mark](https://youtu.be/V0VkmHwVOkQ?t=4862).

Comment: @Ifurini you should put that in an answer. It's not a bad thing to answer possible duplicate story-ID questions, as long as each answer gets tailored to match the details remembered in each question.

Comment: thank you so much, this is it !!!!! I am amazed how fast you could find an anime that it took me years to not find !! Thanks !! :) Do you know the name of the anime in English?

Comment: @Varathius Phoenix 2772 or Firebird 2772

Comment: Does this answer your question? [80s-90s anime (movie or series) in which an armored girl exchanges age with a dying man on a beach](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/200141/80s-90s-anime-movie-or-series-in-which-an-armored-girl-exchanges-age-with-a-dy)