# Looking for the name of a 1980s Sci-fi animated film with one of the characters was a die with arms and legs and used the black dots as pockets

Tags: story-identification, movie, animation

Looking for the name of a 1980s Sci-fi animated film with one of the characters was a die with arms and legs and used the black dots as pockets. I think they have been on a spaceship as well. The die character wasn't one of the main ones.

Comment: There is a dice-shaped side character in the 1980 movie [_"Phoenix 2772"_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phoenix_2772). There is already an [id answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/200231/40711) about it with a youtube link to the whole movie, so you can check if that's the one you are looking for. From a quick glance, the character appears at about [58:35](https://youtu.be/V0VkmHwVOkQ?t=3515).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Ive had a look and I dont think its that one, certainly doesnt match with the images I remember.